# Drag and drop text file into batch file to create folders

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that creates folders using a text file.  But I want to modify the batch file to allow drag and drop any text file to create whatever folder names the text file contains.

Text file contents:

```
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
```

This is what I have now, which works:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in (create_folders.txt) do (

mkdir "%%a"

)
```

This is what I have modified the batch file to (I have added PAUSE so I can see the error):

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do (

mkdir "%%a"

)

ECHO.

PAUSE
```

When I drag the text file into the modified batch file, this is the error I receive:

> A subdirectory or file (*path_to_text_file*) already exists.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do (
    2>NUL mkdir "%%a"
)
```

Explained in [`FOR /F` loop command syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html):

> ```
> FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN (filenameset) DO command 
>
> FOR /F ["options"] %%parameter IN ("Text string to process") DO command
> ```
>
> …  options:
>
> ```
> usebackq   Use the alternate quoting style:                        
>                - Use double quotes for long file names in "filenameset".
>                - Use single quotes for 'Text string to process'
>                - Use back quotes for `command to process`
> ```

Read [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for explanation of `2>NUL` (*redirect error messages to NUL*).